# CMake, specifying packages explicitly. Fail to find package on first run

Tags: curl, build, cmake, zlib, libpng

I'm trying to write the CMakeList.txt and I have problem with finding packages.
I want explicitly specify paths to some libraries, and I have the following code in my CMakeList.txt:

```
set(ZLIB_ROOT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/zlib)
set(ZLIB_LIBRARY zlibstatic)
set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/zlib)
set(PNG_INCLUDE_DIR libs/lpng ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libs/lpng)
set(PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR libs/lpng ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libs/lpng)
set(PNG_LIBRARIES png16_static)
set(PNG_LIBRARY png16_static)
set(JPEG_LIBRARY png16_static)
set(JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libjpeg)
set(JPEG_LIBRARY jpeg)
set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/curl/include)
set(CURL_LIBRARY libcurl)

FIND_PACKAGE(ZLIB REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(PNG REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(JPEG REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(CURL REQUIRED)
```

It works as expected. 
But I want to include the targets of those libraries into the main CMakeList.txt. I do the following thing:

```
add_subdirectory (libs/curl)
add_subdirectory (libs/lpng)
add_subdirectory (libs/libjpeg)
add_subdirectory (libs/zlib)
```

For some reason, the calls to `FIND_PACKAGE(X)` fail inside the libraries. On the first run of cmake, I have the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) (found version "1.2.8")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:124 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
libs/lpng/CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package)
```

On the second run I have different error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
Could NOT find PNG (missing: PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPNG.cmake:121 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
libs/libdvid-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:118 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

On the third run:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) (found version
"7.47.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindCURL.cmake:61 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
libs/libdvid-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:120 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

And finally on the forth run there is no error and everything works as expected.

What I'm doing wrong? As a quick solution, I just removed all `find_package(X)` in all libraries above, and it works fine.

Comment: `As a quick solution, I just removed all find_package(X) in all libraries above, and it works fine.` - Yes, as you include libraries targets directly, `find_package()` doesn't need.

Comment: @Tsyvarev,  yes, but I don't want to modify CMakeLists of libraries. Every new library I include, I have to remove all `find_package`. And I cannot understand why it fails.

Comment: Oh, it is `find_package()` calls from libraries' `CMakeLists.txt` which fail. Actually, `find_package` expects searched library to be **already installed**, not just sourced. You may try to lie to the find script, assigning searched variables directly to non-existed directories, but the find script may have complex logic. which doesn't support that. You may investigage content of `libs/lpng/CMakeLists.txt` and `.../FindZLIB.cmake` for get reason about the first error message. Again, what you are doing is not required to be supported.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, what does `already installed` mean in case of Windows platform?

Comment: `already installed` means that all package *deliverables* (libraries files, public headers, and so on) are placed on their **final locations**, so they can be immediately used for linking and running linked executable. If these "final locations" are not system default ones, you need to hint `find_package` about that locations. In your case, when you call `cmake` binary directory is empty, so all variables contained `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` point to *unexistent* files.